# LineHeight Plugin issue on CKeditor

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, fckeditor, inlineeditbox

I have added CKEdiotr LineHeight plugin in my editor.

Its working fine when i m not setting any toolbar configuration from config file, but wheni enable my toolbar setting its hide.

My Toolbar setting are as follow with "line height" config setting

```
config.extraPlugins = 'lineheight';
config.line_height = "10px;12px;13px;14px;15px;16px;";

config.toolbar = [
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: ['basicstyles', 'cleanup'], items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'] },
    { name: 'styles', items: ['Font', 'FontSize', 'TextColor', 'BGColor'] }];
```

Please let me know where i am missing.
I think i m missing to add Item name in `config.toolbar` item list

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have solved it by now. For those who have this issue, you need to add `lineheight` in the items list.

**Example:**

```
{
    name: 'styles',
    items: ['Font', 'lineheight', 'FontSize', 'TextColor', 'BGColor']
};
```